# RadioGroup getValue does not return correct selected value

Tags: wicket

I'm running into a small issue with  RadioGroup.  My RadioGroup has the values true and false.  The Radio types I have in my radiogGroup use a Model that stores true or false.

On an Ajax onChange event I want to do some handling, and to do so I need to know the selected radio in my radioGroup and another identical radioGroup.  The problem is getValue() only returns the initial value from my POJO.  Whenever I click on a radio button to change the selected Radio getValue() it still returns the initial value.

When I save my changes, my POJO gets the correct value.  I am finding this bizarre, I have spent hours trying to figure our what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to handle some data in the backend i would suggest you override the `wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications()` method of the `RadioGroup` object and then use the `onSelectionChanged()` method (again from the RadioGroup) to handle the logic based on the `newSelection` witch you receive as parameter in the method.

IF you want to update the interface the you would need to use the `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` witch give you access to `AjaxRequestTarget` so you can update the view.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior.html) instead of a [`AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.html).

From the javadoc:

> `public abstract class AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior extends AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`
>
> This is a Ajax Component Update Behavior that is meant for choices/groups that are not one component in the html but many.
>
> Use the normal AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior for the normal single component fields

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the Value (state) from the Checkbox gets pushed to the model. have a look at AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior. See

http://www.jroller.com/karthikg/entry/wicket_and_ajax

they explain a bit about this.

disclaimer: i don't have access to the sources where i have done such a thing and write this only with what i remember from it

Answer (score 0):

Put some code in the question so we can help. For me the solution was the [`processInput()`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html#processInput%28%29) method. Call it on your RadioGroup to update the model attached to the RadioGroup. I do it this way:

My sample Radio:

```
private Radio myRadio() {
  Radio localmyRadio = new Radio("myRadio", Model.of(someValue), myRadioGroup);
  localmyRadio.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {
     @Override
     protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        myRadioGroup.processInput(); //updates the model of the radiogroup
        //do some stuff
        target.appendJavaScript("$(\".jq-ui-button\").button();");
     }
  });
  return localmyRadio ;
}
```

My sample RadioGroup:

```
private RadioGroup myRadioGroup() {
   RadioGroup localmyRadioGroup = new RadioGroup("myRadioGroup", selectedRadioModel);
   localmyRadioGroup.setOutputMarkupId(Boolean.TRUE);
   return localmyRadioGroup;
}
```

This way when i click the radio the model of the RadioGroup gets the value of the variable `someValue`. Read the selected value from the RadioGroup model. In this case it's the value of the variable `selectedRadioModel`.