# Radio button on the Wicket does not work in groups

Tags: java, radio-button, wicket, radio-group

My question is regarding the Framework Wicket, more precisely with the 'Radio' component.
.
The problem is that I am implementing it in html page and the radio buttons are appearing but you can not change option ... even if I create 10 different options can only select the first option ... when I click on the other options first 'radio button' remains marked ...
.
here is the code of java

```
    private IModel<Boolean> selected = new Model<Boolean>();       
    .
    .
    RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup("group", selected);
    form.add(group);

    group.add(new Radio("sim", new Model<Boolean>(true)));
    group.add(new Radio("nao", new Model<Boolean>(false)));
```

Here is the HTML

```
       <wicket:container wicket:id="group">
            <label><input wicket:id="sim" type="radio" name="ticker"/> Sim</label>
           <label><input wicket:id="nao" type="radio" name="ticker"/> Não</label>
     </wicket:container>
```

Otherwise I tried to implement was as follows: JAVA:

```
    private String selected;        
    .
    .
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Sim");
    list.add("Não");
    new RadioChoice<String>("radio",new PropertyModel<String>(this,"selected"),list);
```

the HTML

```
    <span wicket:id="radio" />
```

But the problem persists ... I can only select the first option, by clicking on the other nothing happens. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: A similar question/answer might give you some information:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795182/radiogroup-getvalue-does-not-return-correct-selected-value

Answer (score 1):

Aznbanana9 thank you for sending a reply ... :) but I found the problem, my code was like this:
.

```
<label>    
    <wicket:container wicket:id="group">
        <input wicket:id="sim" type="radio" name="group2" value="true"> Sim<br>
        <input wicket:id="nao" type="radio" name="group2" value="false" checked="checked"> Não<br>
    </wicket:container>
</label>
```

.
Note that the radio is within the tag < label > ... using pure HTML the button works but in 'Wicket' does not work ... I just removed the code from the radio button that was inside the tag < label > 'and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

You have to `name` all the radio elements to the same name that you only want one choice for. If you look at this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), it shows that:

```
 <form>
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
 </form>
```

Is the correct way to implement a radio input.

Comment: I'm just implementing the framework 'wicket', a way of showing the components differs from standard html ... his response did not resolve the problem, in fact the 'radio' component works if you have nothing related to 'wicket' if for the clean html works as wicket does not.

Comment: I didn't notice that you named it. I just assumed that was the problem.